# jboss-seam-pdf inside rich:modalPanel cannot work

Tags: java, jsf, pdf, seam, itext

I have a modalPanel declared as

```
<rich:modalPanel id="printEmailExcel" minWidth="800" minHeight="600" resizable="true">
    <div style="width: 1055px; height: 700px; overflow: auto">
        <s:decorate template="/view/popup/printEmailExcelPopup.xhtml"styleClass="popupCDiv">
            <ui:param name="panelid" value="printEmailExcel" />value="/view/printForm/order.xhtml" />
        </s:decorate>
    </div>
</rich:modalPanel>
```

There is also a commandbutton to show the modalPanel in the same page

```
<s:button oncomplete="#{rich:component('printEmailExcel')}.show()" image="/images/icons/btn_print.gif" ></s:button>
```

inside the printEmailExelPopup.xhtml, there is a

```
<h:form><s:button view="/view/print/order.xthml" /></h:form>
```

order.xhtml :

```
<p:document xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pdf">

The document goes here.

< /p:document>
```

The problem is that when i click the s:button in the modalPanel, it only refresh the whole page and the pdf file IS NOT downloaded. However, if i place the s:button outside the modalPanel(same level of the rich:modalPanel, it works normally). Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

try surrounding your commandButton with form tags.